# Defining functions of symbols and other functions in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I have a function `f = sp.Function('f')` and I have an expression that contains `f`, something like `expr = 2*f + ... + f^2`.

I want to do `expr.subs(f, g)`. In other words, I want to replace `f` with another function `g`. I want to define `g = x + y*h` where `x` and `y` are type `sp.Symbol` and `h` is type `sp.Function`.

However, I cannot even define a function `g` of this kind:

```
import sympy as sp
x, y = sp.symbols('x, y')
g = x * y*sp.Function('h')

----> g = x * y*sp.Function('h')
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Mul' and 'UndefinedFunction'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear to me exactly what you want. You can't literally used undefined functions as algebraic objects in SymPy but you can do essentially the same if you evaluate the function at a symbol. Maybe this helps to figure out your problem:

```
In [5]: f = Function('f')

In [6]: x = Symbol('x')

In [7]: expr = 1 + f(x)

In [8]: expr
Out[8]: f(x) + 1

In [9]: g = Lambda(x, sin(x)-1)

In [11]: g
Out[11]: x ↦ sin(x) - 1

In [10]: expr.subs(f, g)
Out[10]: sin(x)
```